# Php/MYSQL Highscore list only display the max score from his/hers email issues

Tags: php, mysql

I would like my select statement only to print out the highest score of every submission from one email.

Table : **scorelist**

```
name
score
email
createdAT
```

I have try following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, score FROM scorelist ORDER BY score DESC, createdAt ASC
```

This is what I've tried. I think I need a WHERE clause where I ask that email=email = limit 1 but it doesn't work as intended.

The query prints out every instance but not the duplicated scores so if a user have had the same score it's been removed by using DISTINCT of course.

Comment: When you say "doesnt work as intended", what is the output?

Comment: show your data also for more clarification. Also your expected outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want highest score according email, Then use group by clause with `MAX()`. try below query:

```
SELECT name, MAX(score) as score FROM scorelist 
GROUP BY email ORDER BY score DESC, createdAt ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and thanks for understanding what i needed. This query does the trick! Thanks a bunch!